# Running a process in background, linux ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, shell, ubuntu, background

I want to run a .jar file so what I do is that I put "&" at the very end of the command (actually there's no need to log the output , I only want to be able to disconnect from the remote server which hosts my java program, the program itself saves the result after being finished)

I do as it follows , but it doesn't run in the background and it keeps me waiting :

`java -Xmx72G -cp //home/arian/rapidminer/lib/rapidminer.jar com.rapidminer.RapidMinerCommandLine -f //home/arian/RMRepository/testRemote.rmp &`

Any idea that why it doesn't work ?

Thanks , 
Arian

Comment: Don't know what kind of application it is but -Xmx72G is pretty much memory!

Comment: Yes , it's a data mining software , it's already using 12GB for a simple process

Comment: I've edited my answer if ever you are interested with a start/stop script. It would be interresting to mix with other answers (nohup).

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "it keeps me waiting"? Does the `RapidMinerCommandLine`by any chance read from `stdin` or another stream?

If you want to run a process in the background *and* disconnect from the tty session you should use [`nohup`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup), eg.:

```
nohup java -Xmx.... com.rapidminer.RapidMinerCommandLine &
```

(Do remember the `&` at the end!)

You may add `... 1> /dev/null` before the `&` to disregard all `stdout`.

You could also consider the [`screen`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) utility, which allows you to dis- and reconnect to the session, but that's more usable with (semi-)interactive sessions.

(Also, quite a hefty max heap size you're specifying?)

Cheers,

Comment: You have the cause and a solution from @ams. I have added a blurb on how to direct `stdout` to the bit bucket, you can see if it works for you. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSVC, this is an utility interresting to daemonize Java applications

http://commons.apache.org/daemon/jsvc.html

It will give you a var pid file, useful to create a real start/stop script.

EDIT : Other solution, maybe could help

Here is a very old start/stop script I've done for Slackware Linux on embedded systems :

```
#!/bin/sh

application_start() {
  cd /usr/local/YOURHOME
  /usr/lib/java/bin/java \
        -Xmx72G \
        -classpath //home/arian/rapidminer/lib/rapidminer.jar \
        com.rapidminer.RapidMinerCommandLine \
        -f //home/arian/RMRepository/testRemote.rmp &
  echo -n "Starting App daemon:  $CMDLINE"
  ps -Ao pid,command | grep java | grep com.rapidminer.RapidMinerCommandLine | awk '{print $1}' > /var/run/app.pid
  echo
}

application_stop() {
  echo -n "Stopping DataBaseSynchronizerClient daemon..."
  kill `cat /var/run/DataBaseSynchronizerClient.pid`
  echo
  sleep 1
  rm -f /var/run/DataBaseSynchronizerClient.pid
  killall DataBaseSynchronizerClient 2> /dev/null
}

application_restart() {
  application_stop
  sleep 1
  application_start
}

case "$1" in
'start')
  application_start
  ;;
'stop')
  application_stop
  ;;
'restart')
  application_restart
  ;;
*)
  echo "usage $0 start|stop|restart"
esac
```

Comment: I don't have the permission to install things

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why it wouldn't work. It really should, in most shells.

Anyway, if you intend to disconnect you'll usually find that just putting the job in the background is not enough: the disconnect will close the console (which will break many programs, alone) and send a SIGHUP signal (which will cause just about any program to exit).

You should considered using `nohup` to run the program (with the `&`). Alternatively, if you ever do need to come back and interact with the program later then `screen` or `byobu` might fit the bill better. Yet another alternative might be to add the task to your `crontab`.

Comment: Actually when I use nohup , it still blocks me !
`
[1] 12623
user@Server:~$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to `nohup.out'
`

Comment: You're not blocked. A message came out after the prompt, that's all. Try hitting enter and few times.

Comment: NP, that's the problem with background tasks: their output gets all mixed up with the foreground process.

Answer (score 1):

I agree it should work as it is, but I had problems with Java running in background too. My solution was to use the `screen` utility (which normally is installed in most Linux distributions) where you can open a shell from which you can detach. If I remember well the commands are something like this (but there is a good manpage too)

```
screen -S myCustomName # runs a new shell called myCustomName
CTRL + D # detach from the current screen instance
screen -ls # list active screen instances
screen -r myCustomName # reattach to the screen instance.
```

Hope it will solve your problem.